# Did the Buddha ever teach logic?

Tags: mindfulness, practice

Was western logic ever taught by the Buddha? How about Indian logic? How can  logic be useful in the Eightfold Path? How could logic be a hindrance? How could logic be a blessing?

Comment: What do you mean by western logic and indian logic?  and fyu, there is no **blessing** in buddhism

Comment: Woa there buddy, you ever here of the MANGALA SUTTA? Seems your out of your mind, no blessing in Buddhism, indeed!!!

Comment: sorry, I meant FYI, not fyu, indeed I know what it is. and still, there are no blessing in buddhism

Comment: There are many blessings in Buddhism, some are actually what the Buddha taught, some might be the kind of blessing you must be thinking of, like when a monk gives blessings out like money or on behalf of spirits or some such thing. You never heard of the "Mangala" Sutta? It's a great sutta , it tells us what are blessings from the Buddha's mouth, over 30 practical blessings but they may not be the kind of blessing you had might be thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

In one sense the Buddha advised against using deductive reasoning to gain certainty about what brings an end to suffering. From the kalama sutta :

> 4. "It is proper for you, Kalamas, to doubt, to be uncertain; uncertainty has arisen in you about what is doubtful. Come, Kalamas. Do not go upon what has been acquired by repeated hearing; nor upon tradition; nor upon rumor; nor upon what is in a scripture; nor upon surmise; **nor upon an axiom**; nor upon specious reasoning; nor upon a bias towards a notion that has been pondered over; nor upon another's seeming ability; nor upon the consideration, 'The monk is our teacher.' Kalamas, when you yourselves know: 'These things are good; these things are not blamable; these things are praised by the wise; undertaken and observed, these things lead to benefit and happiness,' enter on and abide in them.

Note that logical deduction requires axioms to deduce conclusions from. Logical reasoning doesn't tell us if the axioms are true and therefore it doesn't tell us if the conclusions are true.